# How to show current date? Android app

Tags: java, android, date

I create a Android app and I want to show the current date on screen. I use this code:

```java
Date date = new Date(0);
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
text.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));`
```

But this code shown me date "1.1.1970".

How can I show the current date?

Answer (score 4):

`Date(0)` is the first January 1970, see [the documentation of the Date(long milliseconds) constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29):

> public **Date**(long milliseconds)
>
> Initializes this Date instance using the specified millisecond value. The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT.

To get the current date, use `Date()`, the [constructor without a parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29):

> public **Date**()
>
> Initializes this Date instance to the current time.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
text.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format( Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");   
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = dfDate.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("Date is "+date);
```

Result will be ========> 2012-08-07

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `0`, so replace this: `Date date = new Date(0);` by this: `Date date = new Date();`

As per [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29):

> Initializes this Date instance using the specified millisecond value.
>   The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT.

Since you passed on a value of 0, it was taking the above date and adding 0 milliseconds to it, hence the reason why you got the `1.1.1970` date.

Answer (score 1):

To show the current Date on the Screen do this..

`String s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").format(new Date());`

Now display the **String s** on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` is enough otherwise you get the date 0 seconds after the 01.01.1970 00:00:00 if you call `new Date(0)`

Comment: Calendar.getInstance is better

Comment: yeah but that won't show him his mistake. ... and now i can argue that joda time is better than using calendar

Answer (score 0):

Don't use new Date(0). The parameter is time since the epoch, which is 1.1.1970. Just use new Date().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import "java.util.Date;" and not "java.sql.Date;" or else you wont be able to pass through no parameter.